# If Chrome or Firefox browser (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm using the below code to check if visitor is using Chrome Browser:

```
<?php
function is_chrome()
{
return(eregi("chrome", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}
if(is_chrome())
{
echo 'You are using Google Chrome Browser.';
}
?>
```

also

```
<?php
function is_firefox()
{
return(eregi("firefox", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}
if(is_chrome())
{
echo 'You are using Firefox Browser.';
}
?>
```

is working fine, but how can i combine or how to use "or" function, so to check if httpuseragent contains "chrome" or "firefox"?

Thanks

Comment: `eregi()` is deprecated.  You should avoid using it.

Comment: You do know that your `is_firefox` routine isn't being called?

Comment: to expand on @Brad's point, you would use `preg_match` to perform a regex, but since there's no regex here, `strpos` would be far more efficient: `return strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'chrome') !== false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

> `$a or $b`    TRUE if either `$a` or `$b` is TRUE.
>
> `$a || $b`    TRUE if either `$a` or `$b` is TRUE.

That page also includes examples.

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
if (is_chrome() || is_firefox()) {
echo 'you are using either Chrome or Firefox';
}
```

Because I think your question was : if I have two boolean functions, how can I test if one or the other is true, right?

Comment: Im new in php, this is answer is what i wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function whatBr()
{
    $currentBr = '';
    if(eregi("firefox", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])): $currentBr = 'firefox';
    elseif(eregi("chrome", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) $currentBr = 'chrome';
    endif;
    return $currentBr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "chrome")>0){
 echo "Chromes";
}else if (stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "firefox")>0){
 echo "Firefox: please install Chrome";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php ,i didn`t use it myself but it seems ok or http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2827-PHP-Detects-the-user-browser-type-and-version.html

Comment: browscap.ini is no longer being updated.  I wouldn't recommend using `get_browser()`.  http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/(chrome|firefox)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo 'Hello FF or Chrome!';
}
```